# link in post_id in /me/notifications/unread is wrong

Tags: bug, documentation, notifications

I have run [/me/notifications/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/me-unread-notifications). The response contains `post_id` and there is a link to it.

This link is wrong. **The post is on Stack Apps but the link directs to Stack Overflow:**

[image]

I have hovered my mouse over the link which is shown next to `post_id`.
This link is not present in responses of other API functions that give similar results like [notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification) in [/notifications/unread](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/unread-notifications)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a very minor bug in the documentation page.
The online doc page adds a *convenient* hyperlink to the post (The link part is not in the API's JSON response).  That's a good thing.

Most of the time this is rock solid, but [notifications](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification) span all Stack exchange sites and the API doc pages normally only expect one site at a time.

When the page is making that ***optional convenience*** link, it keys off of the `site` parameter. :

[image: user's screen shot as it should have been posted]

This works fine on all other doc pages, but obviously fails for the few cross-site objects, like notifications.

---

As for the rest, [the documentation clearly says](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/notification):

> `post_id` <kbd>2.1</kbd>       integer, refers to a post, ***may be absent***

(Emphasis added)

`post_id` is present only when the notification refers to a specific post.  Like when it was edited, closed, etc.

Comment: How does that link point to correct post? The link to which `post_id` is pointing to is given in the bottom right side in chrome. Is that the correct link?

Comment: Only the first line in your answer was useful.

Comment: You're right; I did not read your question closely enough.  Revamped my answer.